# Center gridlayout in linearlayout

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a Gridlayout inside a Linearlayout and want the Gridlayout to be horizontally centered (ie. same distance to the left and right):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/outerLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10pt"
    android:paddingRight="10pt"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:columnWidth="200px"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="none"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start..."/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The Gridlayout is centered, but does not appear to be so, since it does not tightly wrap its content (there is still "empty space" inside the Gridlayout on the right side), even though `layout_width="wrap_content"` is set.

Comment: have you tried layout_gravity="center" in linearlayout attributes?

Comment: yes, but it did not center the gridlayout

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **stretchMode** as **spacing width uniform** instead of **none**. Set gravity as **center**.

There are two more options in **StretchMode**. Check this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drrqw.png)

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:columnWidth="200px"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp" />
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but if I don't want that spacing between the grid elements?